# tomcat docker chmod not working correctly when deploying via Kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a docker container via Kubernetes. In my DockerFile, I specify this (neuro:

```
FROM docker/psh-base-centos-tomcat:7.7.1908.1
RUN groupadd -r mygroup && useradd --no-log-init -r -g mygroup mygroup
USER mygroup:mygroup
WORKDIR /home/mygroup
RUN chmod 755 -R /tomcat
RUN chown -R mygroup:mygroup /tomcat
COPY ./target/rest-*.war /tomcat/webapps/rest.war
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/tomcat/bin/startup.sh"]
```

However, when I deploy this service via AKS, logs say this:

```
sh: /tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: Permission denied
```

I manually enabled permission of `catalina.sh` file specifically by adding `RUN chmod 755 -R /tomcat/bin/catalina.sh` to DockerFile, then I re-deployed it and now I get this:

```
touch: cannot touch '/tomcat/logs/catalina.out': Permission denied
/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: line 434: /tomcat/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

It seems like `RUN chmod 755 -R /tomcat` is not working correctly, and I have no idea why. Is there anything I am doing wrong here to get permission for `/tomcat` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a Linux users management issue in your Dockerfile, Dockerfiles are interpreted line by line in the build process (layer per layer) in your case you have set the "neurostar" as a current user in the third line and you want to change  the default user directories access permissions.

This should work for you :

```
FROM docker/psh-base-centos-tomcat:7.7.1908.1 
USER root 
RUN groupadd -r mygroup && useradd --no-log-init -r -g mygroup mygroup 
RUN chmod 755 -R /tomcat 
RUN chown -R mygroup:mygroup /tomcat 
USER mygroup 
COPY ./target/rest-*.war /tomcat/webapps/rest.war 
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/tomcat/bin/startup.sh"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Do you mind changing the content inside? I found that there are some security issue... Please change it to this. Just changing some sensitive info:
`FROM docker/psh-base-centos-tomcat:7.7.1908.1
USER root
RUN groupadd -r mygroup && useradd --no-log-init -r -g mygroup mygroup
RUN chmod 755 -R /tomcat
RUN chown -R mygroup:mygroup /tomcat
USER mygroup
COPY ./target/rest-*.war /tomcat/webapps/rest.war
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/tomcat/bin/startup.sh"]`